# Expected length of the shortest polygonal path connecting random points

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, asymptotics, combinatorial-geometry

$N$ points are selected in a uniformly distributed random way in a disk of a unit radius. Let $L(N)$ denote the [expected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) length of the shortest [polygonal path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) that visits each of the points at least once (the path need not to be closed any may be self-intersecting).

- For what $N$ do we know the exact value of $L(N)$?
- Is there a general formula for $L(N)$?
- What is the asymptotic behavior of $L(N)$ as $N\to\infty$?
- What are the answers to previous questions, if the disk is replaced with a ball?

Comment: I like this problem very much. Where does it come from (homework, textbook, research, etc)?

Comment: I took interest in your question and asked a version of it here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/149643/expected-length-of-the-shortest-polygonal-chain-connecting-n-random-points-in-th

Answer (score 24):

Given: $(X,Y)$ is Uniformly distributed on a disc of unit radius. Then, the joint distribution of $n$ such points, $((X_1,Y_1), ..., (X_n,Y_n))$, each drawn independently, will have joint pdf:

$$f( (x_1,y_1), ..., (x_n,y_n) ) =   \begin{cases}\pi^{-n}&  (x_1^2 + y_1^2 < 1) & \text{ & }  \cdots \text{ & }&(x_n^2 + y_n^2 < 1) \\ 0 & otherwise  \end{cases}$$

Next, let $Z_n$ denote the Euclidean length of the shortest polygonal path that visits each point (at least) once. For any given $n$, it is possible to express $Z_n$ as an exact symbolic construct. This rapidly gets tiresome to do manually, so I have set up a function `PolygonPathMinDistance[points]` to automate same (I have provided the code at the bottom of this post). For example:

- Case $n = 2$:
  With 2 points, the shortest polygonal path $Z_2$ is, of course, ... :

[image]

and so the desired exact solution is:

$$E[Z_2] = E\left[\sqrt{\left(X_1-X_2\right){}^2+\left(Y_1-Y_2\right){}^2}\right] \approx 0.9054$$

where the random variables $(X_1, Y_1, X_2, Y_2)$ have joint pdf $f(\cdots)$ given above.

Although getting a closed form solution for the expectation integral has thus far proved elusive (perhaps transforming to polar coordinates might be a path worth pursuing - see below), the result is just a number, and we can find that number to arbitrary precision using numerical integration rather than symbolic integration. Doing so yields the result that: $E[Z_2] = 0.9054 ...$.

- Case $n = 3$:
  With 3 points, the shortest polygonal path $Z_3$ is:

[image]

and similarly obtain:

$$E[Z_3]  \approx 1.49 ...$$

- Case $n = 4$:
  With 4 points, the shortest polygonal path $Z_4$ is:

[image]

and similarly obtain:

$$E[Z_4]  \approx 1.96 ...$$

... and so on. For cases above $n \ge 5$, the method still works fine, but numerical integration gets less reliable, and other methods, such as Monte Carlo simulation [*i.e.* actually generating $n$ pseudorandom points in the disc (say 100,000 times), evaluating the actual shortest path for each and every $n$-dimensional drawing, and calculating the sample mean] appear to work more reliably. The latter is, of course, no longer an exact conceptual methodology, but as a practical evaluation method, for larger $n$, it appears to become the more practical option.

**Summary Plots and Fitting** 
$$\color{red}{\text{Expected shortest polygon path connecting $n$ random points in a disc of unit radius }}$$

[image]

... and with $n=50, 100$ and $150$ points added:

[image]

The fitted model here is simply:

$$a + b \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

with $a = -0.11$, $b = 1.388$.

**Fitting curves**

A number of 'natural' contenders present themselves, including models of form:

- $a + b n +  c \sqrt{n}$ ... this performs neatly within sample, but as soon as one extends to larger values of $n$, the model performs poorly out of sample, and needs to be re-fitted given the extra data points. This suggests that the true model is not just square root $n$.
- $a  + b n^c$ ... this works very neatly within sample, and outside sample, but the optimal parameter values show some instability as more data values are added.
- $a + b \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ... just 2 parameters, and works absolutely beautifully. The idea for this model was inspired by Ju'x posting. The parameter values are remarkably stable as more data points are added (they remain constant to 2 decimal places, irrespective of whether we use just $n  = 2 ... 20$, or $n = 50$ is added, or $n=100$ is added, all the way up to $n = 300$), as shown here:

[image]

The parameter values for $a$ and $b$ are the same as for the diagram above.

---

**Code for the `PolygonPathMinDistance` function**

Here is some *Mathematica* code for the exact `PolygonPathMinDistance` function that calculates all of the possible relevant permutations involved in calculating the shortest polygon path, as an exact symbolic/algebraic construct:

```
PolygonPathMinDistance[points_] := Module[{orderings, pointorderings, pathsToCheck, ww},
       orderings =  Union[Permutations[Range[Length[points]]], 
                        SameTest -> (#1 == Reverse[#2] &)];
  pointorderings = Map[points[[#]] &, orderings];
   pathsToCheck  = Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, pointorderings];
 Min[Map[Total[Map[EuclideanDistance @@ # &, #1] /. Abs[ww_]->ww]&, pathsToCheck]]
]
```

.

**Alternative specification of problem in Polar Coordinates**

If points are Uniformly distributed on a disc of unit radius and independent, the joint distribution of $n$ points, $((X_1,Y_1), ..., (X_n,Y_n))$, with joint pdf $f(\cdots)$ is given above. Alternatively, consider the transformation to polar coordinates, $(X_i \to R_i cos(\Theta_i)$, $Y_i \to R_i sin(\Theta_i))$, for $i = 1$ to $n$. Then, the joint pdf is:

$$f( (r_1,\theta_1), ..., (r_n,\theta_n) ) =   \frac{r_1 \times r_2 \times \cdots \times r_n}{\pi^{n}}$$

with domain of support, $R_i=r_i \in \{r_i:0<r_i<1\}$ and $\Theta_i=\theta_i \in \{\theta_i:0<\theta_i<2 \pi\}$. Then, the distance between any two random points, say $(X_i,Y_i)$ and $(X_j,Y_j)$ is given by the distance formula for polar coordinates:

$$\sqrt{\left(X_j-X_i\right){}^2+\left(Y_j-Y_i\right){}^2} = \sqrt{R_i^2 + R_j^2 -2 R_i R_j \cos \left(\Theta_i-\Theta_j\right)}$$

Taking expectations then yields the same results as above. For the $n = 2$ case, symbolic integration is a little easier, and one can obtain the result:

$$\begin{align*}\displaystyle E\left[ Z_2\right]   &= E\left[ \sqrt{R_1^2 + R_2^2 -2 R_1 R_2 \cos \left(\Theta _1-\Theta _2\right)}\right] 
 \\ &= \frac{8}{\pi} \int_0^1\int_0^1 |r_1 - r_2| EllipticE[\frac{-4 r_1 r_2}{(r_1-r_2)^2}]r_1 r_2 dr_1\,dr_2   \\ &= \frac{8}{\pi} \frac{16}{45} \approx 0.9054 \text{(as above)}\end{align*}$$

**Extending from a disc to a ball**

There is no inherent reason the same methods cannot be extended to a ball ... just more dimensions (and more computational grunt required).

Comment: Your graph is c*sqrt(N), can you find the c for some large N? then look it up

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri Actually $c \sqrt{n}$ is not the optimal description of the graph. Please see fitted models above ...

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri wrote: `for large n it approaches c*sqrt(N) exactly`. ............ That's because, for large $n$, $\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ -> $\sqrt{n}$. Why limit yourself to asymptotic results?

Comment: Well what if there is no formula at all for small n?

Comment: For N=2 the answer is exactly 128/45pi, that eliminates 1 variable of your formula

Comment: -1. For N=3 the answer is surely known, but not c, so all your formulas are wrong.

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri Perhaps you might consider posting your own solution, rather than leaving unsubstantiated cryptic comments, half of which have been false.

Comment: You should consider deleteing your answer since its wrong and mathematica already comes with a package that solves the problem 100x faster.

Comment: You may now be allowed to bask in the glory of my answer.

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri wrote: "You should consider deleteing your answer since its wrong and mathematica already comes with a package that solves the problem 100x faster." Charming, as always. As to your _Mathematica_ assertions: 1. _Mathematica_ does not have a function that expresses the $Z_i$ as exact symbolic algebraic constructs (which is what this question poses). It does have a `FindShortestTour` function that is a numerical function, and which is exactly what I have used (after adaptation to get the Path) for checking by Monte Carlo methods, and for large $n$.

Answer (score 12):

There is a very elegant theorem published by Beardwood, Halton and Hammersley in 1959 that gives an alsmost-sure convergence for the length of the shortest path divided by $\sqrt{N}$. See this [poster](http://www.theoremoftheday.org/OR/BHH/TotDBHH.pdf) for a statement in a general setting.

Also, the convergence holds for expectations. In 1989, Rhee and Talagrand showed that the length of the shortest path is very tightly concentrated around its mean.

---

Let us give a very elementary proof that there exists constant $c,C > 0$ such that
$$
c \sqrt{N} \leq L(N) \leq C \sqrt{N}.
$$
In order to simplify the presentation I will do the proof for a unit square instead of a disk, but it should work just the same.

**1. Upper bound (deterministic)**

Take the unit square to simplify and split it into $N$ small boxes of area $1/N$ and side length $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, accordingly to the following figure (to be rigourous this is only possible if $N$ is a square, but by monotonicity it is sufficient to treat only this case).

[image]

In each box, consider an arbitrary polygonal line that joins each of the points contained in the box. Its length is at most $\sqrt{2/N}$ times the number of points in the box except one.

Now link the small chains together (for instance, follow the red path): this is done by adding at most $N-1$ lines of length at most $\sqrt{\frac{5}{N}}$. Thus this procedure gives a full polygonal path that visits each of the points. If $B_i$ denotes the number of points in the $i$th box, the length of the total path is at most
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}(B_i-1)_+ + (N-1)\times \sqrt{\frac{5}{N}} \leq (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})\times \frac{N-1}{\sqrt{N}}
$$
since $\sum_{i=1}^N B_i = N$. This gives an upper bound for the length of the shortest path, hence for its expectation. Of course, the constant $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}$ is far from optimal and can easily be improved.

**2. Lower bound (probabilistic)**

Let us scale the $N$ previous boxes by a factor $\frac{1}{2}$, so that the area of each of them is now $\frac{1}{4N}$.

[image: Smaller boxes]

As before, let $B_i$ denote the number of points in the $i$th box. It follows a Binomial$(N,\frac{1}{4N})$ distribution. The shortest path should at least link together the nonempty boxes, and the cost of these links is at least (thanks to the triangle inequality) $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}$ for each nonempty box except the first one. Using the linearity of expectations we see that $L(N)$ is bounded by below by
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}\times \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{B_i \neq 0}-1\right)\right] \geq \frac{\sqrt{N}}{2}\Pr(B_1 \neq 0) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}.
$$
Note finally that
$$
\Pr(B_i \neq 0) = 1-\left(1-\frac{1}{4N}\right)^N \geq 1-e^{-\frac{1}{4}} > 0.
$$

**3. Extension to dimension $d\geq 3$** : The proof readily extends to $c\cdot N^{\frac{d-1}{d}} \leq L(N) \leq C\cdot N^{\frac{d-1}{d}}$

Comment: Hi Ju'x ...$\sqrt{2 n} +  c \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ did not fit the data well, but the second term $c \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ works beautifully -- see updated posting above.

Comment: @wolfies: Nice! I was only interested in a proof that the correct order of magnitude is $\sqrt{N}$ but I am glad that it fits the data.

Comment: @Ju'x: Nice! I think this can be taken further to show that $L(N)\sim c\sqrt{N}$ for a constant $c$. More generally, $L(N)\sim c\sqrt{AN}$ for a bounded domain of area $A$.

Comment: Someone has opened up a question re expected minimum length on the square at: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/149643/expected-length-of-the-shortest-polygonal-chain-connecting-n-random-points-in-th

Answer (score 2):

[$L(2)=128/45\pi$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskLinePicking.html)

L(3) may or may not be extractable from [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskTrianglePicking.html)

I suspect thats all thats known about exact values.

Also, your problem is called Traveling Salesman Problem.